# ggplot2: How to help ggplot2 display correct y-axis range?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to plot random test score data in ggplot2. The scores are broken down by exam, year, and grade level. When I run the script below, the Y axis displays an undesired range. Namely, the range is unordered, whereas I'd like it to be ordered low to high at fixed intervals. Normally, ggplot2 does this ordering by default, but something about the data frame or a setting I'm unaware of has caused this to not happen.

```
grade <- rep(c(5,6,7,8,9),times=6)
years <- rep(c(2008,2009,2010), each=10)
tests <- rep(c("English","Math"),times=3,each=5)
scores <- c(3.3,7.6,10.8,4.8,3.0,-2.8,14.8,12.4,0.3,6.0,7.0,3.1,3.7,-0.5,0.6,6.2,9.6,5.3,1.9,1.3,1.1,0.0,5.5,6.2,0.3,-0.4,2.2,4.9,4.7,2.6)

data2 <- data.frame(cbind(years,grade,tests,scores))

graph_2 <- ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=years, y=scores)) +
         geom_point(aes(color=factor(interaction(grade,tests)),size=1)) +
         geom_line(aes(group=interaction(tests,grade), color=factor(interaction(grade,tests)))) +
         facet_grid(. ~ grade)

graph_2
```

I thought perhaps that ggplot2 think's the data is discrete, but when I tried `is.factor(scores)`, the R console returned `FALSE`.

Comment: You can move the `color` aesthetic to the top-level `ggplot` object, (makes the code shorter) and I would use `facet_wrap` with `ncol = 1`: `graph_2 <- ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=years, y=scores, color=factor(interaction(grade,tests)))) + geom_point(size=1) + geom_line(aes(group=interaction(tests,grade))) +
facet_wrap(~ grade, nrow = 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your data not with `ggplot()`. When you made your data frame you used function `cbind()` inside the `data.frame()`. That made all your columns as factors because Function `cbind()` produces in this case matrix with all data the same type - character. Function `data.frame()` makes data frame but all character columns are converted to factors.

```
data2 <- data.frame(cbind(years,grade,tests,scores))
str(data2)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ years : Factor w/ 3 levels "2008","2009",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ grade : Factor w/ 5 levels "5","6","7","8",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ tests : Factor w/ 2 levels "English","Math": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ scores: Factor w/ 28 levels "-0.4","-0.5",..: 17 27 10 20 15 3 12 11 5 24 ...
```

If you remove the `cbind()`, numeric columns are treated as numeric and plot looks as expected.

```
data2 <- data.frame(years,grade,tests,scores)
str(data2)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ years : num  2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
 $ grade : num  5 6 7 8 9 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ tests : Factor w/ 2 levels "English","Math": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ scores: num  3.3 7.6 10.8 4.8 3 -2.8 14.8 12.4 0.3 6 ...
```

Comment: Perfect! Here I was thinking `cbind()` was necessary, this is much better.

Comment: You are already putting your variables in one data frame with `data.frame()`, so `cbind()` is unnecessary.